# IPTables: introduce a policy for a chain so that I can maintain the drop policy/rule without having to delete it when I need to add a new accept rule?

Tags: security, iptables, vpn, firewall, subnet

Say I have a chain introduced with `iptables -N SERVICES-VPN`.

But then I want this chain to drop everything... so `iptables -A SERVICES-VPN -j DROP`.

The problem here is that I may need to add rules later to be accepted. Every time I need to add them, I have to manually delete the drop rule (annoyingly by line number, right?), and then introduce the new rules to accept that service, then reintroduce the drop rule again `iptables -A SERVICES-VPN -j DROP`.

This can even be seen as a security hole, where a botnet could be waiting for me to open all the ports by delete the DROP rule to do something, where the last line of defense, the firewall, is what's protecting the machine in question.

This problem doesn't exist for policies, where something like `iptables -P INPUT DROP` will still allow me add new rules, and if no rule exists, it'll drop the connection. What's the best way to achieve this with chains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem here is that I may need to add rules later to be accepted. Every time I need to add them, I have to manually delete the drop rule (annoyingly by line number, right?), and then introduce the new rules to accept that service, then reintroduce the drop rule again iptables -A SERVICES-VPN -j DROP.

Or, rather than using `-A` to **A**ppend, **A**dd **A**fter, which adds any new rules behind the existing rules in a chain you use the option

**`-I`** to **Insert** new rules *at the beginning of the (existing) chain,* without first deleting any of the existing rules that need to come behind the rule you’re adding.

Answer (score 0):

Split the chain in two with a list of allow rules and another chain which looks up allow rules and drops afterward.

Something which looks like this:

```bash
$ iptables -N SERVICES-VPN
$ iptables -N SERVICES-VPN-ACCEPT
$ iptables -A SERVICES-VPN -j SERVICES-VPN-ACCEPT
$ iptables -A SERVICES-VPN -j REJECT
```

Hopefully you don't have a dirty script at startup that does this but a neatly formatted `iptables-restore`-compatible file that makes this atomic which would eliminated the race-conditions you mention.

Hopefully you also move to `nftables` (`nft` on the CLI) since it's [not deprecated](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6739041) and more flexible (this could likely be achieved with two separate chains for VPN/non-VPN).

Edit: the `iptables` deprecation can be debated but from my understanding of it, while there are tools to ease the transition from `iptables` to `nftables` including kernel-side compatibility modules, I don't expect them to last forever so I'll keep this here but feel free to read the comments from @A.B below for different point of view. The main point with regards to this question was that it offers more flexibility which might make the solution easier to implement/maintain.

Comment: Thank you. The split solution may be a good idea. Thank you. Though I do have a "dirty script"... because I need my firewall to be stateless and reproducible. Also are you saying iptables is deprecated? I'm confused.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist no, iptables is not deprecated. iptables-legacy (rather than iptables-nft) is probably.

Comment: An `iptables-save` file (which is a text file you can edit and reads much like a series of shell commands) is much more reproducible than a series of commands which may or may not all succeed, in addition to being reloadable at will while `iptables -N "${CHAIN}"` will fail if the chain already exists. Also yes, `iptables` is deprecated and has been for a while, in most distributions it is now a script that transforms rules into [`nftables`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/) format but you miss out on `nftables`' advanced features.

Comment: @Ginnungagap that's iptables-nft : it's not a script, it's a compatibility *kernel* API (+ of course adequate userland tools).

Comment: Ah didn't know they bothered to make a kernel API to accommodate `iptables`, I always assumed it was a userland compatibility layer. Thanks for the info, will edit it in!

Comment: @A.B, do you have a source for that? From my reading it's just a compatibility `iptables` binary that speaks the `nftables` kernel API. So it's **only** adequate userland tools, no kernel-side support.

Comment: @Ginnungagap to tell it in a short way: everything that can be translated into nftables native ruleset is, anything left that can't (the special xtables matches and targets such as `-j LED`) is using the same match and target kernel module that -legacy uses: this is part of the compat layer. There's a compile option about this: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_COMPAT.html

Comment: Support is needed both from kernel and from userland. For the end-user typing the `iptables` command, that makes no visible difference (or if there is it's probably a bug or a missing feature)

Comment: So am I supposed to use `nftables` instead of `iptables`, and translate all the commands to `nftables` syntax? Is this the way?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I'm just saying that having to move from iptables to nftables because" iptables is deprecated" is not true. Such move should be done because nftables is a superior tool to iptables, but there's no need to move (and in a few cases, eg the [`-j LED`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#LED) target) iptables is still needed. Both can co-exist (with some care and pain, especially when a tool like Docker doesn't know anything about nftables), especially when iptables is iptables-nft rather than iptables-legacy.

Comment: That's fair. I'm OK with iptables so far. I also heavily use docker, so it makes sense not to complicate things.